# Sqlite date between

Tags: sqlite, date

can you please help me why this code does not work?
I dont understand why the result include "2017".

SQLLITE

**QUERY**

```
SELECT issue_date as count FROM tablename where issue_date >= "08/08/2016" and issue_date < "09/01/2016"
```

**Result**

"08/08/2017"

"08/11/2017"

"08/18/2017"

"08/18/2017"

"08/22/2017"

"08/22/2017"

"08/28/2017"

"08/31/2017"

**Create query**

CREATE TABLE tablename (
    issue_date datetime text not null
}

**Insert query**

INSERT INTO tablename (issue_date) values ("08/31/2017");

Comment: Because it is comparing the values as strings, not as dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing your dates in a non ANSI compliant format.  As there is no formal date type in SQLite, and all dates are essentially stored as strings, your current date comparison will behave and sort as if you are comparing to text.  It won't work, because you have the month first, followed by the day, followed by the year.  To get text comparisons of dates to work correctly, use a format something like this:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

You should change the format you use to store dates, but one workaround would be to build the issue date in the correct format and then do the comparison, also against a date string in the same correct format:

```
SELECT
    issue_date AS count
FROM tablename
WHERE
    SUBSTR(issue_date, 7, 4) || '-' ||
    SUBSTR(issue_date, 1, 2) || '-' ||
    SUBSTR(issue_date, 4, 2) BETWEEN '2016-08-08' AND '2016-09-01'
```

Comment: @m0skit0 Without even knowing what actual data is in the OP's table, how can you say my answer is giving still a wrong result?

Comment: Because 08/08/2017 is not between 2016-08-08 and 2016-09-01.

Comment: @m0skit0 You are missing the point.  The dates you see in the OP are only being returned, incorrectly, because as _text_ they happen to lie in between the _strings_ `08/08/2017` and `08/31/2017`.  Get it?  Those dates are not the intended logic at all here.

Comment: I know that, you can check the comment I made before you answered. In your answer though you have `Result "08/08/2017` at the end. I'm not sure what is that supposed to mean if it is not the result of your query.

Comment: @m0skit0 Rats...I am on a cell phone right now and I didn't see that...leftover from copying something from the OP.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No problem. After your comments I kind of figured out it was probably a typo :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will change the string format "yyyy-mm-dd".

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's [data types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) does not have a real DATETIME type. It only has NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT and BLOB. Any other type is converted to these, so what it is doing in your case is storing those values as strings, and this comparing as strings.

I personally prefer to store the dates as UNIX timestamps (hence integers) to avoid complicating the SQL queries and simplify the whole thing (although the values in database will become less human-readable).

Answer (score -1):

Because you specified the query with AND. So it matches your query. Use BETWEEN expression.

```
expression BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with AND? It must fullfil both conditions.